# pandas groupby two columns and summarize by mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5]
df['view'] = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A','B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A','B', 'A', 'B']
df['value'] = np.random.random(12)


    id view     value
0    1    A  0.625781
1    1    B  0.330084
2    1    A  0.024532
3    2    A  0.154651
4    2    B  0.196960
5    3    A  0.393941
6    3    B  0.607217
7    3    A  0.422823
8    3    A  0.994323
9    4    B  0.366650
10   4    A  0.649585
11   5    B  0.513923
```

I now want to summarize for each `id` each `view` by mean of 'value'.
Think of this as some ids have repeated observations for view, and I want to summarize them. For example, id 1 has two observations for A.

I tried

```
res = df.groupby(['id', 'view'])['value'].mean()
```

This actually almost what I want, but pandas combines the `id` and `view` column into one, which I do not want.

```
id  view
1   A       0.325157
    B       0.330084
2   A       0.154651
    B       0.196960
3   A       0.603696
    B       0.607217
4   A       0.649585
    B       0.366650
5   B       0.513923
```

also res.shape is of dimension (9,)

my desired output would be this:

```
id  view    value
1   A       0.325157
1   B       0.330084
2   A       0.154651
2   B       0.196960
3   A       0.603696
3   B       0.607217
4   A       0.649585
4   B       0.366650
5   B       0.513923
```

where the column names and dimensions are kept and where the id is repeated. Each id should have only 1 row for A and B.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) or parameter `as_index=False` in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), because you get `MuliIndex` and by default the higher levels of the indexes are *sparsified*  to make the console output a bit easier on the eyes:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5]
df['view'] = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A','B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A','B', 'A', 'B']
df['value'] = np.random.random(12)
print (df)
    id view     value
0    1    A  0.543405
1    1    B  0.278369
2    1    A  0.424518
3    2    A  0.844776
4    2    B  0.004719
5    3    A  0.121569
6    3    B  0.670749
7    3    A  0.825853
8    3    A  0.136707
9    4    B  0.575093
10   4    A  0.891322
11   5    B  0.209202
```

```
res = df.groupby(['id', 'view'])['value'].mean().reset_index()
print (res)
   id view     value
0   1    A  0.483961
1   1    B  0.278369
2   2    A  0.844776
3   2    B  0.004719
4   3    A  0.361376
5   3    B  0.670749
6   4    A  0.891322
7   4    B  0.575093
8   5    B  0.209202

res = df.groupby(['id', 'view'], as_index=False)['value'].mean()
print (res)
   id view     value
0   1    A  0.483961
1   1    B  0.278369
2   2    A  0.844776
3   2    B  0.004719
4   3    A  0.361376
5   3    B  0.670749
6   4    A  0.891322
7   4    B  0.575093
8   5    B  0.209202
```

Comment: cool, thanks. Which of the two ways is 'better' (e.g. faster,..)

Comment: First is more general, second works with `mean`, `sum`. But I think performance is same.